# Manipulating data in a tuple from dictionary keys

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a list of tuples (variable name 'values') in the format

```
(1, 'K', '-', 0.8878048780487805)
(2, 'Y', '-', 0.32882882882882886)
(3, 'E', '-', 0.7216494845360825)
(4, 'Y', 'B', 0.13963963963963963)
(5, 'V', '-', 0.28169014084507044)
(6, 'E', '-', 0.39690721649484534)
.....
```

And I have this dictionary

```
ratios = {'K': 1.1512, 'A': 1.217, 'R': 1.1048, 'N': 1.242, 'D': 1.184,
      'C': 1.237, 'Q': 1.1364, 'G': 1.2381, 'H': 1.2174, 'I': 1.1657,
      'L': 1.1657, 'M': 1.1914, 'F': 1.2182, 'P': 1.1691, 'S': 1.1923,
      'T': 1.2113, 'W': 1.2555, 'Y': 1.1847, 'V':1.2254}
```

What I would like to do is go through my list and divide the element in index 3 by the value in the dictionary that corresponds to the letter in index 1. For example, 0.8878... would be divided by 1.1512 because of the K, for the next one 0.3288.... would be divided by 1.1847 because of the Y, and so on. I haven't found a way to do this yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your list of tuples look in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension should work great here

```
tuple_list =[(1, 'K', '-', 0.8878048780487805),
(2, 'Y', '-', 0.32882882882882886),
(3, 'E', '-', 0.7216494845360825),
(4, 'Y', 'B', 0.13963963963963963),
(5, 'V', '-', 0.28169014084507044),
(6, 'E', '-', 0.39690721649484534)]

ratios = {'K': 1.1512, 'A': 1.217, 'R': 1.1048, 'N': 1.242, 'D': 1.184,
      'C': 1.237, 'Q': 1.1364, 'G': 1.2381, 'H': 1.2174, 'I': 1.1657,
      'L': 1.1657, 'M': 1.1914, 'F': 1.2182, 'P': 1.1691, 'S': 1.1923,
      'T': 1.2113, 'W': 1.2555, 'Y': 1.1847, 'V':1.2254}

[tup[3]/ratios.get(tup[1],1) for tup in tuple_list]
```

use `get` so it will not throw an error if key is not present in `ratios`

**Output**

```
[0.7711995118561331,
 0.2775629516576592,
 0.7216494845360825,
 0.11786919864914291,
 0.22987607380860978,
 0.39690721649484534]
```

Comment: If OP wants to do it in place: ```tuple_list = [(*t[:3], t[3]/ratios.get(t[1],1)) for t in tuple_list]```

Comment: @FlorianHat You cannot do in place as you are dealing with tuples which are immutable so either way you have to create a new tuple. Hope it helps

Comment: So to replace the original list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in values:
    print(row[1], row[3]/ratios[row[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_tuple_list = [
    (1, 'K', '-', 0.8878048780487805),
    .....
]
result = {}
for (idx, key, _, number) in my_tuple_list:
    result[key] = number / ratios[key]

print(result)
```

This solution shows how to unpack a list of tuples in a clear manner that may be easier to read than list comprehensions